# How to understand the 'check for race ' comment in FutureTask.removeWaiter() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

As code shown below in `FutureTask.java` (**Jdk1.7**):

```
/**
 * Tries to unlink a timed-out or interrupted wait node to avoid
 * accumulating garbage.  Internal nodes are simply unspliced
 * without CAS since it is harmless if they are traversed anyway
 * by releasers.  To avoid effects of unsplicing from already
 * removed nodes, the list is retraversed in case of an apparent
 * race.  This is slow when there are a lot of nodes, but we don't
 * expect lists to be long enough to outweigh higher-overhead
 * schemes.
 */
private void removeWaiter(WaitNode node) {
    if (node != null) {
        node.thread = null;
        retry:
        for (;;) {          // restart on removeWaiter race
            for (WaitNode pred = null, q = waiters, s; q != null; q = s) {
                s = q.next;
                if (q.thread != null)
                    pred = q;
                else if (pred != null) {
                    pred.next = s;
                    if (pred.thread == null) // check for race
                        continue retry;
                }
                else if (!UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, waitersOffset,
                                                      q, s))
                    continue retry;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

We can find that there has two comments:

> check for race

And

> restart on removeWaiter race

---

This is a simple image that shown the state change in `removeWaiter`:

[image]

There is my understanding and question:

**Race condition**: When a thread successfully finds the `pred` node, and another thread try to remove `pred` node, race happend.

**In my opnion**: `q.next`,`q.thread` and `pred.thread` are both `volitile`,so if current thread continue race with others threads, the result will also valid.

**Question**: Why Doug Lea choose **restart race** rather than **continue race**, or is there something wrong for my opinion?